# Excel: delimited data in two columns, match elements between columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi everyone and thank you in advance for any insights

My Excel data looks as below

```
Cell A1               Cell B1
x | y | z             1 | 2 | 3
```

I need to match between the two and create a dataset as below:

```
x             1
y             2
z             3
```

Hope that makes a little bit of sense...

Starting data is over 20K rows long.
Data in both cells A1 and B1 are delimited, but they don't always contain the same number of elements, but they always have the same number of elements *between them*, for example:

```
    Cell A2                    Cell B2
    d | e                       5 | 6
    
    Cell A3                   Cell B3
 f | g | h | i              7 | 8 | 9 | 10
```

I eventually need to amend all my data to look like the below - with the letter and the number in separate columns, for example

```
Column H       Column I
 x                  1
 y                  2
 z                  3    
 d                  5
 e                  6
 f                  7
 g                  8
 h                  9
 i                 10
```

Hope that makes a little bit of sense! I'm confusing myself...

I've tried switching text to columns and experimenting with pivot tables but no luck. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

edit: should have added that the above are dummy data, my real data are not of fixed length.

edit2 (so sorry) - I've included a screenshot that hopefully explains what I need a little bit better... Top 2 rows is what I have, and from row 7 [in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNQKL.png)  is what I need.

Comment: The Data set, should that be in one cell or many?  What version of Excel are you using.

Comment: Hi Scott, appreciate the quick response! I'm getting hopeful! I've included some edits in my initial post, do they answer your question at all? I'm using Excel for Mac 2016.

Comment: This is going to require VBA.

Comment: I suspected as much! Better get on the tutorials, in the off chance that someone is kind enough to post the VBA here :)

Comment: It's a little clunky, but you could do this without VBA. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but here's a non-vba method of achieving your task.

First, determine the max number of values you can see in your data. Let's assume it's 4. Insert 4+1 (5) columns between your current A and B columns.

Second, use the text-to-columns wizard to separate your data (you have bar delimiter, so that's easy to achieve via the wizard). Do this for both data sets. So, each cell will have a unique value.

Now you should have two "sets" of data.

Select set 1 (A1:D3) then right-click and define name as "first_value".

Select set 2 (F1:I3) then right-click and define name as "second_value".

Next, input these formulas:

```
L1: =INDEX(first_value,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS(first_value)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS(first_value),COLUMNS(first_value))+1)

M1: =INDEX(second_value,1+INT((ROW(F1)-1)/COLUMNS(second_value)),MOD(ROW(F1)-1+COLUMNS(second_value),COLUMNS(second_value))+1)
```

Drag down your formulas as far as you need to until you receive a #REF error.

Now you need to decide how to treat your empty rows. They will currently have 0's in both columns L and M. You could copy these full columns to another sheet, paste as special values to remove formulas, and then perform your additional clean-up on those 0's. Sort and delete is one option. As long as a combination of 0 0 is never true data, then this is probably the easiest way to remove it. If you happen to have 0 0 in your actual data, then you'll need to modify the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below.

To use - select the range of cells you want to transform. The selected range must have 2 columns.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SplitAndPivot()

Dim r As Range
Dim msg_result As Integer
Dim msg_title As String
Dim exit_suffix As String
Dim rw As Range
Dim nms As String
Dim ids As String
Dim new_sheet As Worksheet
Dim new_sheetname As String
Dim new_sheetrow As Integer
Dim arr_nms() As String
Dim arr_ids() As String
Dim arr_i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheet_prefix As String

sheet_prefix = "SplitAndPivot"
msg_title = "Split and pivot"
exit_suffix = vbCrLf & "No transformation done."


msg_result = MsgBox("Do you want to remove " & sheet_prefix & " sheets created earlier?", vbYesNoCancel, msg_title)

If msg_result = 6 Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Left(ws.Name, Len(sheet_prefix)) = sheet_prefix Then
            ws.Delete
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

ElseIf msg_result = 2 Then
    MsgBox "You selected Cancel or closed the message box." & exit_suffix, vbInformation, msg_title
    Exit Sub
End If


msg_result = MsgBox("Have you selected the cells you want to transform?", vbYesNoCancel, msg_title)

'Yes = 6
'No = 7
'Cancel = 2
'X = 2

If msg_result <> 6 Then
    MsgBox "You selected No, Cancel or closed the message box." & exit_suffix, vbInformation, msg_title
    Exit Sub
End If

Set r = Selection

If r.Columns.Count <> 2 Then
    MsgBox "You must select a range with two columns." & exit_suffix, vbCritical, msg_title
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


new_sheetname = sheet_prefix & "_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD_HHmmSS")

Set new_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

With new_sheet
    .Name = new_sheetname
    .Cells(1, 1) = "Name"
    .Cells(1, 2) = "ID"
    .Cells(1, 3) = "SourceRange"
End With

new_sheet.Name = new_sheetname

new_sheetrow = 2


'Iterate through each selected row, split the values and pivot them on to the new sheet
For Each rw In r.Rows

    nms = rw.Cells(1, 1)
    ids = rw.Cells(1, 2)
    
    Debug.Print "Processing:", rw.Address, nms, ids
    
    arr_nms = Split(nms, " | ")
    arr_ids = Split(ids, " | ")
    
    If UBound(arr_nms) <> UBound(arr_ids) Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Number of ID elements is different to number of Name elements in range " & rw.Address & exit_suffix, vbCritical, msg_title
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For arr_i = 0 To UBound(arr_nms)
        Debug.Print arr_i, arr_nms(arr_i), arr_ids(arr_i)
        With new_sheet
            .Cells(new_sheetrow, 1) = arr_nms(arr_i)
            .Cells(new_sheetrow, 2) = arr_ids(arr_i)
            .Cells(new_sheetrow, 3) = rw.Address
        End With
        new_sheetrow = new_sheetrow + 1
    Next arr_i
    
Next rw

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Finished transforming selected range.", vbOKOnly, msg_title

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table14"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Col A", type text}, {"Col B", type text}}),

//create a "List" from each column
//then create a "Table" from the two lists
    Result = Table.FromColumns(
                {List.Combine(List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[Col A], each Text.Split(_,"|")))} & 

                //Transform Col B values to numbers depending on your actual data
                {List.Transform(
                    List.Combine(List.Transform(#"Changed Type"[Col B], each Text.Split(_,"|"))), each Number.From(_))},
                type table[Col A=text, Col B=Int64.Type])
in
    Result
```

[image]